# Limiting thread memory access per thread in GHC

Tags: multithreading, haskell, memory-management, concurrency, ghc

I'm wondering, is it possible to limit the amount of memory a thread uses? I'm looking at running a server where untrusted user code is submitted and run. I can use SafeHaskell to ensure that it doesn't perform any unauthorized IO, but I need to make sure that a user's code doesn't crash the entire server, i.e. by causing a stack overflow or out-of-memory heap error.

Is there a way to limit the amount of memory each individual thread can access, or some way to ensure that if one thread consumes a massive amount of memory, that only that thread is terminated?

Perhaps, is there a way that when any thread encounters an out of memory error, I can catch the exception and choose which thread dies?

I'm talking more about concurrency, in the sense of forkIO and STM threads, rather than paralellism with par and seq.

Note: this is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297654/how-to-cap-memory-usage-of-haskell-threads), but it never received an answer to the general problem, rather the answers dealt with the specific scenario of the question. Additionally, it's possible that since 2011, something might have changed in GHC 7.8, maybe with the new IO manager?

Comment: Yes, there has been progress on this since 2011. See http://ezyang.com/rlimits.html . Space limits will hopefully be available in some future GHC release, probably 7.10.

Comment: Do you know if there's any sort of experimental version which could be used in the meantime?

Comment: There are instructions on how to obtain and compile their branch of GHC on the page I linked.

Comment: You can give [mueval](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mueval) a spin.  I don't think it enforces stack limits but I do believe heap size is controlled.

Comment: Stack limits wouldn't be too much of a problem, since each thread has its own stack, right? I suppose I can't ask for much, but do you know what kind of performance mueval gets? Either way, it looks awesome, thanks!

Comment: In the mean time see https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/GHC-Conc-Sync.html's `enableAllocationLimit`. As noted, it puts more a quota on CPU (for which allocation count is a proxy) rather than memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Haskell, but in general, the answer to your question is no.  In all programming languages/runtimes/operating systems/etc. that I know of, threads are nothing more than different paths of execution through the same code.  The important thing in this case, is that threads always share the same virtual address space.

That being said, there is no technical reason why a memory allocator in your particular language & runtime system could not use a thread-specific variable to track how much has been allocated by any given thread, and impose an arbitrary limit.

No technical reason why it couldn't do that, but if thread A allocates an object which is subsequently accessed by thread B, thread C, thread D,...  Then what sense does it make to penalize thread A for having allocated it?  There is no practical way to track the "ownership" of an object that is accessed by many threads in the general case, which is why none of the languages/runtimes/OSes/etc. that I know of attempt to do it.