# May I limit memory usage per function/monad/thread in Haskell?

Tags: multithreading, haskell, memory, ghc

I'm working on a research compiler project intended to work as a service. One of the requirements is that certain users might have a limited memory usage (e.g., "calls from IP *a.b.c.d* may use up to 30mb of heap memory") while handling its calls.

My prototype implementation, written in C, simply uses a memory pool indead of `malloc`'ing directly (which is actually pretty hard to get right due to effective types). Manual memory management, though.

Is there any way to achieve this in Haskell, by limiting heap usage on a function, monad, or lightweight thread? (I'd accept suggestions of other functional languages which might allow me to do this.)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to limit? Limiting arbitrary memory for arbitrary Haskell code probably wouln't be possible, but you could limit access to some specific resource by hiding it behind a type class.

Comment: Operating system processes can have limited memory. One possible solution is to fork a new process and [`setResourceLimit`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.2.1/docs/System-Posix-Resource.html) on the new process, and communicate with it with something like [Remote](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/remote-0.1.1/docs/Remote.html). You'd need to restrict code run in the new process to something less powerful than `IO ()`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to limit overall memory usage for that compilation process. Those can be really expensive, I'd be vulnerable to DoS if I don't somehow limit heap usage.

Comment: It sounds more appropriate to be doing this at a higher level. Linux has lots of facilities for controlling resource usage in all sorts of ways, with lots of pre-existing tooling. Maybe spin up a docker container with `--ulimit` set for each user or something

Comment: I do understand that this would be a feasible solution, but processes and OS threads are heavyweight. In this scenario, it would be best to keep using C with my own green threads and assembly context switch.

Comment: I think Erlang has per-thread heaps (to send data to another thread, you have to copy it), so I assume you can limit their size. I don't see how "the memory usage of a thread" makes sense in a language with automatic memory management and a shared heap.

Comment: @ReidBarton, Erlang? That's really nice! Too bad it's an un(i)typed language...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the latest versions of GHC, it is possible to set per-thread allocation counters and limits, using `setAllocationCounter` and `enableAllocationLimit` from [`GHC.Conc`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/GHC-Conc.html#g:3). When a limit is set and the counter reaches 0, the thread receives an asynchronous exception.

The counters measure *allocation*, and not the size of the live set. For example, this code hits the limit, despite its live set never becoming very big:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NumDecimals #-}
module Main where

import Data.Foldable (for_)
import System.IO
import GHC.Conc (setAllocationCounter,enableAllocationLimit)

main :: IO ()
main = 
  do setAllocationCounter 2e9
     enableAllocationLimit
     let writeToHandle h =
            for_ ([1..]::[Integer])
                 (hPutStrLn h . show)
     withFile "/dev/null" WriteMode writeToHandle
     return ()
```

Allocation is a bit crude as a measure, but it can still be useful to detect some "out of control" computations.

[This blog post](https://simonmar.github.io/posts/2017-01-24-asynchronous-exceptions.html) by Simon Marlow goes into more detail.

Comment: Close enough. Thanks.

Comment: Also noteworthy is that `try` or `catch` will cause the exceptions to be deferred.

Docs: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/GHC-Conc.html#v:enableAllocationLimit

Comment: Another thing the documentation doesn't clarify: what does that number denote? Is it the number of bytes? The number of allocation calls the thread makes? All that makes it very hard to reason about the function and the documentation is lacking there. 

The linked post by Simon Marlow also doesn't really talk about `setAllocationCounter` per se. 

It would also help if you clarified in your example why you're using `2e9` and what the number denotes.