# Test that a Haskell function has a space leak

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a collection of example space leaks in Haskell, and would like to write a test suite to catch myself in case I insert any examples that don't actually leak space.

Is there way to test the examples without making a separate executable for each one?

Comment: Neil Mitchell has a very effective and very low-tech technique described on his blog: [Detecting Space Leaks
](http://neilmitchell.blogspot.com/2015/09/detecting-space-leaks.html).

Comment: In some future it would be possible to check this using static analyzers :) If this can be formalized then detecting space leaks is only matter of implementing algorithm.

Comment: @Cactus: That's a great article. Unfortunately I don't know if it's possible to catch the exceptions generated when you run out of memory (which makes sense). I tried generating the exception in another process with `System.Posix.process.forkProcess` and catching it with `ClassyPrelude.catchAny`, but it still slips through and crashes the test suite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can detect a space-leak with  test, but you can't prove an absence of space leaks. Even if memory profile relatively low it may just point that space leak very small and you have not made enough iterations.

To detect space leaks you may use allocation limits and counters as described here [May I limit memory usage per function/monad/thread in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42353661/may-i-limit-memory-usage-per-function-monad-thread-in-haskell)